# Serviço feito em Delphi "se matar" ou dar Stop

Tags: delphi

Gostaria de saber qual comando utilizar para um serviço Windows "se matar".

Por se tratar de um serviço não tenho a opção `Application.Terminate`.

Preciso verificar uma certa data, e se passou dessa data, o serviço deve ser parado ou se matar.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Experimente o comando `Halt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o comando `Halt` tanto no `VCL` quanto no `Process`.
Caso o Halt não seja suficiente você ainda pode um outro comando o `ExitProcess`.

A forma de uso de ambos é:

```
Halt(x);
ou
ExitProcess(x);
```

Obs: Onde **x** é um código inteiro de retorno para o SO entender o motivo da finalização da Aplicação! Ou seja, é uma mensagem de saída! Não é Obrigatório ser informado valor para esse parâmetro!

Comment: OK, coloquei no fonte só não vou conseguir testar agora. Mas assim que eu testar eu volto aqui e comento ou aceito a resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: Tudo bem amigo, o comando correto para seu caso, e será bem melhor de usar será o `ExitProcess(0);` Em caso de Aplicação o `Halt` pode deixar resto da aplicação na memória não fechando completamente!

Comment: Júnior, o comando ExitProcess(0) foi o que eu precisava. Ele para o serviço. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Para matar o processo estando fora dele.

```
function StopProcess(ExeFileName: string) : Integer;
const
  PROCESS_TERMINATE = $0001;
var
  ContinueLoop: BOOL;
  FSnapshotHandle: THandle;
  FProcessEntry32: TProcessEntry32;
begin
  Result := 0;
  FSnapshotHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  FProcessEntry32.dwSize := SizeOf(FProcessEntry32);
  ContinueLoop := Process32First(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
  while Integer(ContinueLoop) <> 0 do
  begin
    if ((UpperCase(ExtractFileName(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile)) =
      UpperCase(ExeFileName)) or (UpperCase(FProcessEntry32.szExeFile) =
      UpperCase(ExeFileName))) then
      Result := Integer(TerminateProcess(
                        OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE,
                                    BOOL(0),
                                    FProcessEntry32.th32ProcessID),
                                    0));
     ContinueLoop := Process32Next(FSnapshotHandle, FProcessEntry32);
  end;
  CloseHandle(FSnapshotHandle);
end;
```

E para mata-lo estando no process.

```
Application.Terminate;
```

Comment: Esse comando "Application.Terminate" eu uso quando o aplicativo é VCL.Forms, funciona, porém no serviço eu digito "Application." e não tem a opção "Terminate". Mas obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Veja essa:

```
uses WinSvc;

//
// start service
//
// return TRUE if successful
//
// sMachine:
//   machine name, ie: \SERVER
//   empty = local machine
//
// sService
//   service name, ie: Alerter
//
function ServiceStart(
  sMachine,
  sService : string ) : boolean;
var
  //
  // service control
  // manager handle
  schm,
  //
  // service handle
  schs   : SC_Handle;
  //
  // service status
  ss     : TServiceStatus;
  //
  // temp char pointer
  psTemp : PChar;
  //
  // check point
  dwChkP : DWord;
begin
  ss.dwCurrentState := -1;

  // connect to the service
  // control manager
  schm := OpenSCManager(
    PChar(sMachine),
    Nil,
    SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);

  // if successful...
  if(schm > 0)then
  begin
    // open a handle to
    // the specified service
    schs := OpenService(
      schm,
      PChar(sService),
      // we want to
      // start the service and
      SERVICE_START or
      // query service status
      SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);

    // if successful...
    if(schs > 0)then
    begin
      psTemp := Nil;
      if(StartService(
           schs,
           0,
           psTemp))then
      begin
        // check status
        if(QueryServiceStatus(
             schs,
             ss))then
        begin
          while(SERVICE_RUNNING
            <> ss.dwCurrentState)do
          begin
            //
            // dwCheckPoint contains a
            // value that the service
            // increments periodically
            // to report its progress
            // during a lengthy
            // operation.
            //
            // save current value
            //
            dwChkP := ss.dwCheckPoint;

            //
            // wait a bit before
            // checking status again
            //
            // dwWaitHint is the
            // estimated amount of time
            // the calling program
            // should wait before calling
            // QueryServiceStatus() again
            //
            // idle events should be
            // handled here...
            //
            Sleep(ss.dwWaitHint);

            if(not QueryServiceStatus(
                 schs,
                 ss))then
            begin
              // couldn't check status
              // break from the loop
              break;
            end;

            if(ss.dwCheckPoint <
              dwChkP)then
            begin
              // QueryServiceStatus
              // didn't increment
              // dwCheckPoint as it
              // should have.
              // avoid an infinite
              // loop by breaking
              break;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;

      // close service handle
      CloseServiceHandle(schs);
    end;

    // close service control
    // manager handle
    CloseServiceHandle(schm);
  end;

  // return TRUE if
  // the service status is running
  Result :=
    SERVICE_RUNNING =
      ss.dwCurrentState;
end;
```

http://www.chami.com/tips/delphi/031598D.html